# Does body side molding damage the paint?

Tags: toyota, body-work, rav4, trim

I just got a new 2016 RAV4. I'm thinking about getting a body side molding to protect it from door dings. They will install it right in the Toyota dealership

I have three questions:

**1. In general:** Is `bsm` a good protection against door dings?
 **2. When installing it:** Can`bsm`damage the paint? They will only glue it, no screws or nails, right?
 **3. When removing it:** If I want to remove it later, will this damage the door paint? I know it will be slightly off color since there was no exposure to sunlight. But everything will eventually even out I hope

I read Toyota [reviews](http://www.topix.com/forum/autos/toyota-camry/T7KNSSJUAKT2TPCN4/p16). So paint is one of the weak spots for Toyota. So I'm worried about it

Thank You

Comment: I've added the relevant 'trim' and 'bodywork' tags, which cover bodyside mouldings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Depends on how long it is on there, when the glue dries out it can be hard to remove without damaging the paint (if you need to do remove them for some reason), also the paint will not match anymore as the rest of the car will fade slightly, the paint under the molding will not.
3. See 2

Comment: Thank you +1. Will they use glue only?. They will not use bolts or nails to attach it my my doors, will they? It's ALWAYS only glue, right?

Comment: I can think of a good reason to remove it. Let's say the `bsm` took the hard hits, and now looks all nasty. So, I want to replace it with a new `bsm`. They will have to remove the old pair of `bsm`

Comment: @Emily Ask them. If they use glue only (which they should), it will be possible to remove without damaging the paintwork by heating it and cleaning off the residue.

Comment: @Emily Usually they use 3M double stick tape made for body moldings.

Comment: @Emily You have to double check that they will only use double sided tape to install the `bsm`. Some shops employ neanderthals that will not care about your property.  I'm an ex-toyota technician and suggest that you have these installed by a reputable body shop and not the dealership. The dealership will probably sub-contract a body shop to do it (thus costing you more) or have shop staff (read: not a technician) install it.